# Entity Framework Stored Procedure with Multiple Record Set not accepting my parameter

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ado.net

I'm using Microsofts suggested solution for using Entity Framework to read multiple record sets from a stored procedure but added a small snippet to use parameters and it's not working.  I've had a co-worker look at the code and tell me it looks like it should work so I thought I'd ask here.

Using the 4.5 framework is not an option.  I'm stuck with 4.0 and etity framework 4.4.

```
            App MyApp = (App)Application.Current;
            EnterpriseEntities EE = new EnterpriseEntities();
            EE.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = MyApp.EnterpriseEntityConnectionString;

            var cmd = EE.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[spSelectWaterUsesByRightID]";
            var param = cmd.CreateParameter();


            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            param.ParameterName = "@RightID";
            param.Value = this.RightID;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);


            EE.Database.Connection.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<WaterUses> ListOfWaterUses = (((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)EE)
                    .ObjectContext
                    .Translate<WaterUses>(reader, "WaterUses",System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly)).ToList();
```

When I get to the ExecuteReader line I get an error message that the stored procedure requires Parameter @RightID but that's what I'm passing.   I checked the parameter count right before it executes and it's at 1.

Comment: Microsoft's solution is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

somewhere before `cmd.ExecuteReader()`.